# Include subselect only if there is one result using tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

We have an invoice, a invoice detail and a order table and the tables are linked by the invoice detail rows because the invoice details are grouped by delivery date so a invoice often covers multiple order numbers.

Now I would like to build a view that would display the order number if there is only one order involved in the invoice by using a subselect of some kind.

I came up with this one but it still generates an error reporting that the subquery return more than one result

```
SELECT Invoice.Id, Invoice.TotalAmount, 
(SELECT DISTINCT OrderId  FROM InvoiceDetail 
WHERE InvoiceDetail.InvoiceId = Invoice.Id
GROUP BY OrderId HAVING COUNT(DISTICT OrderId) = 1) AS OrderId 
FROM Invoice
```

Any ideas to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
  Invoice.Id,
  Invoice.TotalAmount,
  OneOrder.OrderId
FROM 
  Invoice
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT   InvoiceId, MIN(OrderId) OrderId
    FROM     InvoiceDetail 
    GROUP BY InvoiceId
    HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT OrderId) = 1
  ) OneOrder ON OneOrder.InvoiceId = Invoice.Id
```

Comment: Putting the OrderId in an aggregate worked because the orderid can be left out in the grouping clause. Using an left outer join made it include all invoices with a null value for the orderid for invoiced with multiple orders.

Answer (score 1):

Tested correct:

```
SELECT Id, TotalAmount, OrderInfo.OrderId 
  FROM Invoice 
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT InvoiceId, OrderId 
        FROM InvoiceDetail 
        JOIN Invoice  
          ON InvoiceDetail.InvoiceId = Invoice.Id  
       GROUP BY InvoiceId, OrderId
      HAVING COUNT(OrderId)=1
    ) AS OrderInfo
    ON Invoice.Id=OrderInfo.InvoiceId
```

Notice lack of DISTINCT in HAVING clause, which is incorrect (it would cause multiple order ids to count as one, breaking the expected behavior)

Comment: Fix the typo from the original code: `DISTICT` should be `DISTINCT`

Comment: `GROUP BY InvoiceId, OrderId` is *guaranteed* to fulfill `HAVING COUNT(OrderId)=1` - but that's not what the OP has asked for, IMHO.

Comment: This query would return return multiple invoices with the same invoice number if the invoice has multiple related orders. The goals is to get all the invoices but only the order number is there is one single related order

Comment: @jhoefnagels: You're right it would return multiple rows, but all with the same OrderId. If I understood correctly, there can be N OrderIds with an InvoiceId, and he'd be interested only in those where there is only one OrderId. I don't see how you would find that out if you group on OrderId?

Comment: Like I said, I did test this with various scenarios and its behavior for them is correct (including 0, 1, >1 orders with the same order id for a particular invoice id). If someone can think of a scenario where it would not work, I would be happy to check it out and modify the query.

Comment: I would like the query tor return a null value for the OrderId if there are more than 1 related orders for an invoice. Now it returns either only the invoices with one order or multiple results for one invoice that has multiple related orders.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may just be the typo in the `HAVING` clause.  See DISTICT.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`GROUP BY OrderId`
to
`GROUP BY InvoiceDetail.InvoiceId`